# Can't figure out this filter() recursion error

Tags: python, list, recursion, filter

The problem is I have to write a program which takes in a list of words and an integer and returns the words whose length is longer than that integer. I have to use filter() only.
This is what I wrote :

```
def filter(list,integer):
    largenum = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > integer, list ))
    return largenum
inp = input("Enter the words: ").split()
intr = input("Enter the integer: ").split()

print (filter(inp,intr))
```

When I run this and give the inputs, it gives an error:

> Runtime error: Maximum recursion depth exceeded.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I got it. Such a silly mistake(s) XD.
1.) I changed filter(list,integet) to filterthis(string,integer)
2.) intr = input("Enter the integer: ").split() to intr = int(input("Enter the integer: ")

Comment: 1. Your recursive function is missing a base case. It will infinitely recur until it reaches the maximum recursion limit 2. You are naming your variable as `list` which shadows the builtin

Comment: Why did you need to write filter function?

Comment: "I have to use filter() only" ?your function or builtin `filter` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `integer` as `list`.So use `integer[0]`.Then `input` returns `str`.So use `int(integer[0])`.

Then you are using `filter` as your `function name`.So this will override the `builtin` function `filter`.Also you are passing your list as `variable` `list`.It will also override the `builtin callable list`.You can try this

```
def myfilter(mylist,integer):
    largenum = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > int(integer[0]), mylist ))
    return largenum
inp = input("Enter the words: ").split()
intr = input("Enter the integer: ").split()

>>>print(myfilter(inp,intr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written filter function which calls itself without a base case.

Rename your filter function.

```
In [8]: def my_filter(l, i):                                                                                                        
   ...:     largenum = filter(lambda x: len(x)> i, l)  # if python3, use list(filter)                                                                        
   ...:     return largenum                                                                                                         
   ...:                                                                                                                             

In [9]: inp = ["LOL", "DA", "YAYASTRING"]                                                                                                                     

In [10]: intr = 2                                                                                                                   

In [11]: my_filter(inp, intr)                                                                                                       
Out[11]: ['LOL', 'YAYASTRING']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of `filter` will shadow the python built-in which has the same name. So when you make a call to it from inside your `filter`, it's not really to the built-in you are intending to call, but to your function itself. Since there is no stopping rule for the recursion, it ends up exceeding permissible stack depth.

Same goes for `list`. The function argument with the same name will shadow the builtin python `list` container.

Also, you'll need to cast the second argument to `int` before passing it to the function.

For code:

```
def fil(lst, integer):
    return filter(lambda x: len(x) > integer, lst)

>>> fil(['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doin'], 3)
['Hello', 'doin']
```